# How do sourcemaps work in React with sentry and production code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sentry, source-maps

I'm after an understanding on how sourcemaps work in the following scenario.

I've got code deployed to production and I want to upload sourcemaps to `sentry`. There is a process & docs for adding this to the CI pipeline.

However, I'm wanting to bypass that and get sourcemaps onto sentry quickly to start debugging errors.

I'm wondering how sourcemaps map to my code and then show errors in sentry? If I run `yarn build` locally (but I do a production build) and then upload the sourcemaps from that, will that map to my actual production build that is sitting in google cloud hosting?

I'm just trying to work out how the two link together

Comment: Does https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/legacy-sdk/sourcemaps/ help?

Comment: @evolutionxbox sort of but that's the legacy docs. and I'm using esbuild anyway. but im trying to understand on a more granular level what is happening and if my hypothesis of uploading it manually would work

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter where you upload the source maps from. One thing that you should consider however is that the source maps and the source files do still need to match/be compatible!